# installing data fixture on symfony2

Tags: php, git, symfony

My exact version is 2.3.6; I have trouble when I try to make the "composer update". I receive the follow message:

```
[RuntimeException]                                                                                                                
  Failed to clone https://github.com/doctrine/data-fixtures.git, git was not found, check that it is installed and in your PATH env.                                                                                                                                
  sh: 1: git: not found
```

My file of the composer.json on the part of required is the follow:

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.3.*",
        "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
        "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "dev-master",
        "doctrine/data-fixtures": "dev-master"
    },
```

Comment: `git was not found` so I guess you have checked that git was installed on the computer?

Comment: yes i did it on the beginning

Comment: So if you type `git` you have something showing up in the command?

Comment: Thanks i did solved that. Was the version of the git squeezeme. Thanks for the help.